Parse an URI with multiple hosts possible?
I have a Spring-Boot app and need to parse a MariaDB-connection URL - for reasons.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mariadb://host1:3306/mydb

This worked well so far.
URI uri = URI.create (mystring.substring ("jdbc:".length ()));
System.out.println (uri.getScheme());  // mariadb
System.out.println (uri.getHost());    // host1
System.out.println (uri.getPort());    // 3306
System.out.println (uri.getPath());    // mydb

Now I introduce a cluster to my DB.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mariadb:sequential://host1:3306,host2:3306/mydb

Now my parsing does not work anymore.
The "sequential" I can remove. But not sure with the multiple hosts.
Can I handle that with URI or something similar?
Otherwise I need to build a RegExp.

What's your expected output here? I'm guessing the two URIs mariadb://host1:3306/mydb and mariadb://host2:3306/mydb?

Yes - I would be also happy if it get only the 1st host:port

jdbc:mariadb:sequential://host1:3306,host2:3306/mydb is - according to RFC 2396 and RFC 3986, Section 3.2 - not a valid URI. So I do not believe that we can rely on Java's URI class. Looks like we would need to code something ourselves.

That was my expectation - but since Mysql/Mariadb must use it I was in hope that there is some existing object I can use but do not know yet.

Why do you think that it "must use it"?

EDIT: I meant Spring - I specify my cluster URL that way and it is working - so they must parse it.

Spring nor any JDBC client doesn't need to parse JDBC URLs. I guess each JDBC driver is responsible of parsing it's own URLs

This has nothing to do with Spring. This is probably native/backed into the MariaDB driver to pass a URL (as it normally isn't valid). Spring doesn't parse anything it just passes it through to the driver. But why would you need to parse it in the first place? Putting System.out in your Spring Boot application is generally not a good idea.
